# Use is_authenticated using OneToOneField relation with User

Tags: python, django, authentication, one-to-one

I have built a model which have a OneToOne relation with the User object in Django like this :

```
class Student(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But in the HTML file, the filter `{% if user.student.is_authenticated %}` does not work but the filter `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` works. I thought that the Student class inherits the attributes from the User class.

Is there an other possibility to create custom users from the User class with the possibility to use `{% if user.student.is_authenticated %}` ? I want also to have the possibility to use for example `{% if user.teacher.is_authenticated %}`.

Comment: No it does not inherit, these are just two models (tables) where one of the tables refers to the others by specifying the primary key.

Comment: How can I do to decide either I prefer teacher or student to be authenticated (or both of them) to see the content allowed to them ?

Comment: you can check if it is an authenticated teacher with `{% if user.is_authenticated and user.teacher %}` for example to check if the user is authenticated and a teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that the Student class inherits the attributes from the `User` class.

**No**, it does not inherit, these are just two models (tables) where one of the tables refers to the others by specifying the primary key.

You thus check this with:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    …
{% endif %}
```

or if you want to know whether the user of a `student` is authenticated, you can work with:

```
{% if mystudent.user.is_authenticated %}
    …
{% endif %}
```